# Wifi Network keeps asking for password not connecting, Linux Mint 20.3

Tags: linux, networking, linux-mint, wifi-driver

WSIWYG, I am unable to connect to wi-fi and when I attempt to the password prompt appears 2-3 times before the connection fails. I am using a Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB3.0 802.11ac 1200M Adapter with [this driver](https://github.com/morrownr/88x2bu-20210702).

This is the output of `inxi -Fxz`:

```
Network:   Device-1: Intel I211 Gigabit Network vendor: ASUSTeK driver: igb v: 5.6.0-k port: e000 bus ID: 03:00.0 
           IF: enp3s0 state: down mac: <filter> 
           Device-2: Realtek USB3.0 802.11ac 1200M Adapter type: USB driver: rtl88x2bu bus ID: 1-7:4 
           IF: wlx1cbfce78b64c state: down mac: <filter>
```

The wi-fi network I'm trying to connect to uses WPA2 Personal encryption, and I am able to connect to it fine from other Linux machines with different hardware.

Edit: Here's some journalctl output for NetworkManager:

```
xx:19:22 device (wlx1cbfce78b64c): Activation: starting connection 'Auto ..' ({UUID})
xx:19:22 audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="{UUID}" name="Auto .." pid=2114 uid=1000 result="success"
xx:19:22 device (wlx1cbfce78b64c): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
xx:19:22 device (wlx1cbfce78b64c): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
xx:19:22 device (wlx1cbfce78b64c): Activation: (wifi) access point 'Auto ..' has security, but secrets are required.
xx:19:22 device (wlx1cbfce78b64c): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
xx:19:22 device (wlx1cbfce78b64c): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
xx:19:22 device (wlx1cbfce78b64c): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
xx:19:22 device (wlx1cbfce78b64c): Activation: (wifi) connection 'Auto ..' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
xx:19:22 Config: added 'ssid' value '..'
xx:19:22 Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
xx:19:22 Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
xx:19:22 Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK'
xx:19:22 Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
xx:19:22 Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
xx:19:39 device (wlx1cbfce78b64c): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
xx:19:39 device (p2p-dev-wlx1cbfce78b64c): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
xx:19:46 device (wlx1cbfce78b64c): supplicant interface state: scanning -> associating
xx:19:46 device (p2p-dev-wlx1cbfce78b64c): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> associating
xx:19:47 device (wlx1cbfce78b64c): Activation: (wifi) association took too long
xx:19:47 device (wlx1cbfce78b64c): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
xx:19:47 device (wlx1cbfce78b64c): Activation: (wifi) asking for new secrets
xx:19:48 connection disconnected (reason -3)
xx:19:48 device (wlx1cbfce78b64c): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
xx:19:48 device (p2p-dev-wlx1cbfce78b64c): supplicant management interface state: associating -> disconnected
xx:19:48 connection disconnected (reason 1)

PROMPT 

xx:20:52 device (wlx1cbfce78b64c): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
xx:20:52 device (wlx1cbfce78b64c): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
xx:20:52 device (wlx1cbfce78b64c): Activation: (wifi) connection 'Auto ..' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
xx:20:52 Config: added 'ssid' value '..'
```

and the corresponding wpa_supplicant output:

```
xx:19:46 wlx1cbfce78b64c: Trying to associate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (SSID='..' freq=5180 MHz)
xx:19:46 wlx1cbfce78b64c: CTRL-EVENT-STARTED-CHANNEL-SWITCH freq=5180 ht_enabled=1 ch_offset=1 ch_width=40 MHz cf1=5190 cf2=0
xx:19:48 wlx1cbfce78b64c: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx reason=3 locally_generated=1
xx:19:48 wlx1cbfce78b64c: CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT status_code=1
xx:19:48 wlx1cbfce78b64c: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
```

PROMPT is where I am prompted to enter the wifi password.
If there's anything else I should say just let me know.

Comment: On this machine, update the WiFi driver, restart, and test

Comment: So how have you configured the Realtek adapter to use the WPA2 key/password?

Comment: @John I am using the latest version of this specific open source driver. I have tried restarting many times.

Comment: @kreemoweet I'm not sure I understand your question. A password entry prompt appears when I try to connect, I enter the password, it disappears and reappears after a few seconds without connecting me.